# Why is Basic Authentication from the Client Considered Secure

Tags: ajax, authentication, api-design

I'm not looking for opinion here, I realize how easily this question could get off topic, so let me explain.

I'm trying to figure out why we would use Basic HTTP Authentication at all if the username and password are simply passed as base64 encoded parameters from an AJAX request.

I understand the difference between Authentication and Authorization, but I'm not sure I see why we would even have the Authentication step in place for HTTP if it would take 10 seconds for a user to find it and then simply replicate the parameters in every API request from then on?

I've not found any good answers to this question in my research. I only find how to use Basic authentication.

Comment: For a malicious user to find it you mean? That's why we have HTTPS.

Comment: @Brian, but even over https all the user would need to do is look in your source code and find the credentials?

Comment: Passwords are hashed on the backend. So theoretically speaking, it's a one-way encryption. That's why password recovery actually lets you choose a new password, not retrieve it.

Comment: So the password that would be stored in a js file would be the hashed version, and not the plain text version? like user:l3kkjlakl3j@kjasdkfl

Comment: Ideally stored in a database, but yes. If you're interested in knowing more about how to make the request more secure, you might also want to look up asymmetric encryption (TLS), which is used for encrypting traffic.

Comment: Okay, that all helps. Thanks @Brian